# EPPlus chart from list of single excel cells. How?

Tags: epplus

I want to make an excel chart, using EPPlus, from a list of single cells. Say I want a pie with three pieces getting their values from cells C4, C6 and C8. How?

These two attempts is among those that does not work:

```
ExcelChart chart = ExcelWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart(myTitle, eChartType.Pie);
ExcelAddress values = myWorkSheet.Cells["C4;C6;C8"]; // => 'Invalid Address format'
ExcelAddress values = myWorkSheet.Cells["C4,C6,C8"]; // => No chart is made
```

So, is it possible? If so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line with cell names separated by commas is the format you want.  Did you specify both the x and y axis range?  Maybe show your code where you actually add the series.

You should be using `ExcelRange` not Address.  Like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Chart_From_Cells_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207020/epplus-chart-from-list-of-single-excel-cells-how
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var myWorkSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
        var ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Chart");

        //Some data
        myWorkSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "A";
        myWorkSheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 100; myWorkSheet.Cells["A3"].Value = 400; myWorkSheet.Cells["A4"].Value = 200; myWorkSheet.Cells["A5"].Value = 300; myWorkSheet.Cells["A6"].Value = 600; myWorkSheet.Cells["A7"].Value = 500;
        myWorkSheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "B";
        myWorkSheet.Cells["B2"].Value = 300; myWorkSheet.Cells["B3"].Value = 200; myWorkSheet.Cells["B4"].Value = 1000; myWorkSheet.Cells["B5"].Value = 600; myWorkSheet.Cells["B6"].Value = 500; myWorkSheet.Cells["B7"].Value = 200;

        ExcelRange values = myWorkSheet.Cells["B2,B4,B6"];
        ExcelRange xvalues = myWorkSheet.Cells["A2,A4,A6"];

        const string myTitle = "Chart 1";
        ExcelChart chart1 = ExcelWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart(myTitle, eChartType.Pie);
        chart1.Series.Add(values, xvalues);

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Using ExcelRange instead of ExcelAddress did the trick.

Comment: if I have only values and want to use index (0, 1, ...N) as xvalues?

Comment: @constructor You will need to use the Series.Add overload that accepts strings and set the second parameter to be empty.  If you cant get it post a separate question with your code.

Comment: Anyone how comes across this post there is a bug with `ExcelRange` and union cell selectors (cells separated with commas) as of version 4.1.0.  See this post for a work around:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870194/epplus-chartpie-barchart-selectedb2-b36-b38-etc-excel-cells