# EPPlus chart(pie,barchart) selected(B2,B36,B38) .. etc excel cells

Tags: charts, epplus

I have similar to the link below problem.

[EPPlus chart from list of single excel cells. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207020/epplus-chart-from-list-of-single-excel-cells-how/40869458?noredirect=1#comment68954388_40869458)

I tried the code but it shows it twice in the chart. For example:

This code show excel chart -> select data-> horizontal(category) axis labels tab you show 100,100,300,600 write. What is the reason for this? The chart is written twice the first data I did not find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just discovered a bug with EPPlus.  Shame on me for not noticing that with that post you reference.  It seems that when using the Excel union range selector (the cell names separated by commas) the iterator for the `ExcelRange` class returns a double reference to the first cell, in this case `B2`.

A work around would be to use the other overload for `Series.Add` which will take two string ranges.  Here is a unit test that show the problem and the workaround:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Chart_From_Cell_Union_Selector_Bug_Test()
{
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Chart_From_Cell_Union_Selector_Bug_Test.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var myWorkSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
        var ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Chart");

        //Some data
        myWorkSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "A";
        myWorkSheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 100; myWorkSheet.Cells["A3"].Value = 400; myWorkSheet.Cells["A4"].Value = 200; myWorkSheet.Cells["A5"].Value = 300; myWorkSheet.Cells["A6"].Value = 600; myWorkSheet.Cells["A7"].Value = 500;
        myWorkSheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "B";
        myWorkSheet.Cells["B2"].Value = 300; myWorkSheet.Cells["B3"].Value = 200; myWorkSheet.Cells["B4"].Value = 1000; myWorkSheet.Cells["B5"].Value = 600; myWorkSheet.Cells["B6"].Value = 500; myWorkSheet.Cells["B7"].Value = 200;

        //Pie chart shows with EXTRA B2 entry due to problem with ExcelRange Enumerator
        ExcelRange values = myWorkSheet.Cells["B2,B4,B6"];  //when the iterator is evaluated it will return the first cell twice: "B2,B2,B4,B6"
        ExcelRange xvalues = myWorkSheet.Cells["A2,A4,A6"]; //when the iterator is evaluated it will return the first cell twice: "A2,A2,A4,A6"
        var chartBug = ExcelWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart("Chart BAD", eChartType.Pie);
        chartBug.Series.Add(values, xvalues);
        chartBug.Title.Text = "Using ExcelRange";

        //Pie chart shows correctly when using string addresses and avoiding ExcelRange
        var chartGood = ExcelWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart("Chart GOOD", eChartType.Pie);
        chartGood.SetPosition(10, 0, 0, 0);
        chartGood.Series.Add("Content!B2,Content!B4,Content!B6", "Content!A2,Content!A4,Content!A6");
        chartGood.Title.Text = "Using String References";

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I will post it as an issue on their codeplex page to see if they can get it fixed for the next release.

Comment: thanks for your reply to me.  problem temporarily resolved.

Comment: I posted this as an issue on code plex: http://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15561  @ocean: Make the question as answered or helpful if that is the case.